# Why is my Logitech C270 camera not working with my Windows 10 machine?

Tags: drivers, camera

I installed the correct drivers for my operating system, but my Logitech C270 camera is still not working. I do not have an antivirus. There is an exclamation mark on the camera icon in the device manager. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that an inbuilt camera? Or an external camera?

Comment: If it is an external camera, How have you connected it? And how have you ensured you installed right drivers?

Comment: @saaranshgarg It is an external camera. I connected it, and I installed the correct drivers from the manufacturer's website.

Comment: What have you tried until now? Have you tried uninstalling the device completely and just plug it to see if windows recognizes it ?